# my code does not plot correct surface charge density for a (two parts) composite sphere. positive and negative charges must appear in pink and blue

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

[image: SCDD.png]
[S_CHARGE_Density_D.mat](https://s25.picofile.com/file/8453231184/S_CHARGE_Density_D.mat.html)
[polarmap.m](https://s25.picofile.com/file/8453231318/polarmap.m.html)

> how can I modify my code to plot a two colors sphere (blue for negative charges and pink for positive charges and white for zero)?
> my colormap is polarmap, but the image that the code generates is not polar.
> would you please help me?

```
load('S_CHARGE_Density_D.mat') ;

X = X./1e-3 ; 
Y = Y./1e-3 ;
Z = Z./1e-3 ; 
Figure = figure('Name','SCDD','NumberTitle','off'); 

% Create axes 
axes1 = axes('Parent',figure); 
hold(axes1,'on'); 

colormap(axes1,'polarmap'); 

surf(X,Y,Z,SCDD,'Parent',axes1,'EdgeLighting','gouraud','EdgeColor','none'); 

colorbar(axes1) 

xlabel('x (mm)','FontWeight','bold'); 
ylabel('y (mm)','FontWeight','bold'); 
zlabel('z (mm)','FontWeight','bold'); 

title('SCDD','FontWeight','bold'); 

box(axes1,'on'); 
grid(axes1,'on'); 
axis(axes1,'tight'); 
view(axes1,-44,38); 
set(axes1,'DataAspectRatio',[1 1 1],...  
    'FontSize',12.5,'FontWeight','bold','Projection',...
    'perspective','XDir','reverse','YDir','reverse'); 

% savefig('SCDD.fig')
```

Comment: your `SCDD` variable that you pass in the call to `surface` is a `128x128x3` matrix. This is interpreted by Matlab as a grid full (128x128) of color [R,G,B] triplets. Matlab does not apply a colormap scaling, it just display the color you specified. If you want the color to represent the electric charge, this should be a grid full (128x128) of **scalar** values. So your call should look like: `surf(X,Y,Z,ElectricCharge, ...)`. The 4th argument `ElectricCharge` should be a 2D matrix of size 128x128. Then Matlab will apply the colormap to such a surface.

Comment: thanks, your guidance was very useful, would you please take a look at my other problem and help me if you can. the address of this my new question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73923057/would-you-please-help-me-to-modify-my-matlab-code-that-is-about-calculation-of-s